# form submissions with AJAX

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, jquery

So here is my problem in localhost. I am passing in the search parameter to my Home controller like:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=site_url('home/index');?>">
```

When I do this, my ajax menu is populated correctly

```
       ----------
SEARCH:| mot    |
        ----------------------------
       | motorcyles ...            |
       | motorhomes ...            |
       | motorola ..               |
       -----------------------------
```

.

On my web server, the only way to submit the form is with `<form method="post" action="<?site_url('home/index');?>">` if I put the "=" in there, it does nothing. If I use

```
<?php echo site_url('home/index');?>">
```

it will also display nothing.

Additionally, when I type in search terms on my web server

```
        ----------
 SEARCH:| mot    |
         ---------
```

nothing, no errors, no results. If I submit the form, I get back the correct results only after pressing submit.

My controller is getting the correct results from the database, here is how I'm encoding my results array:

```
if ( $this->input-> is_ajax_request())
    {
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        $this->output->set_header("Expires:Mon, 4 Apr 1994 04:44:44 GMT");
        $this->output->set_header("Content-type:application/json");

        echo json_encode($results);
        exit();

    }

    else {

        $data['results'] = $results;

         }
```

There are no errors with my js file. I have CSRF turned off. Why is this happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var action= $('form').attr('action');
    var results = $('#results');

    function ajax_search(search) {

        $.post(action, {
            search: search
        }, function(data) {

            if(data.length) {

                var el = $('<ul/>');

                $.each(data,function(i,item){
                    $(el).append('<li><span class="Course_Name">' + 
                    item.course_name_highlighted + '</span> &ndash; <span class="FirstName">' + item.FirstName + '</span> &ndash; <span class="LastName">' 
                    + item.LastName + '</span> &ndash; <span class="COURSE_ID">'+item.COURSE_ID +'\n</span></li>');
                });

                $(results).empty().append(el);
            }



            else{
                $(results).empty();
            }
        }, 'json');

    }




    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        var search = $(this).val().replace(/^\s+l\s+$/g, "");

        if(search.length > 1)

        {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

            var wait = setTimeout(function() 
            {
                ajax_search(search)

            }, 400);

            $.data(this,'timer', wait);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is, and I've read it three times. Maybe you should not use space in your if() `$this->input-> is_ajax_request()`

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but, since `site_url()` doesn't return anything: have you loaded the URL helper?

Comment: @cubsink That would do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an form submission you want the results to display after a keyup event correct(ie: when someone types) ?

Try

```
$("input[name='search']").on('keyup', function(){

     var $this = $(this),
         results = $("#results"),
         timeout = '';

     // ------ delayed keyup event  ------//

     //reset initial timeout
     if(timeout)
     {
         window.clearTimeout(timeout);
         timeout = NULL;
     }
     // ------Timeout Listener ----- //
     timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        //send ajax request
        var searchTerm = $this.val();

     }, 1000);  // listens for when last key has been pressed after 1sec

});
```

Comment: I already have the Javascript to do all of this, the problem is it works on localhost but not on web server, and I don't know why.

Comment: Then it could be any number of things.  try echo site_url('home/index') outside of the form itself, if no value its a routing error or url helper is not loaded.  Try console for any js errors, check config file, domain might need to be set, the list goes on...

Comment: well the url helper is loaded and site_url  redirects correctly just the list is not being populated unless i hit submit, what is setting the domain mean?

Comment: Do you see the `home/index` URL in the HTML source? A form with an empty action will by default submit to itself, so it would submit correctly, even though there's no action URL.

Comment: @Mudshark YES, don't you? By domain I mean $config['base_url'] = 'domain'

Comment: @Philip well since he's not showing us any of the outputted HTML, I can't check...

Comment: @Mudshark Line 2 mate: <form method="post" action="<?=site_url('home/index');?>">

Comment: @Philip that's not HTML source, I want to see what `<?=site_url('home/index');?>` or `<?php echo site_url('home/index'); ?>` outputs to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `ajaxSubmit` might be handy for you here.
http://be.twixt.us/jquery/formSubmission.php

or
$("#formId").ajaxSubmit({url: 'xxx.php', type: 'post'})

or
$("#formId").ajaxForm({url: 'xxx.php', type: 'post'})

or you can use 
$.post('xxx.php', $('#formId').serialize())

**Note**: $.post is just a short hand of jQuery ajax with some difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be displayed when user types anything. User jquery ajax form submition instead of normal form submition.

Use keyup even on document load Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;
   $(".search").keyup(function() 
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "relative path to file", //this is the file which you normally use with action=""
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          "do whatever you want with data, example append or prepend data to any div";
        }
        });
      });
   });
});
```

and use like statement with query to show result on you index file

```
$q=$_POST['searchword'];

mysql_query("select * from table where fieldname like '%q%' order by fieldname LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

After this use while statement to fetch results...

Answer (score 0):

you want to data on key press so put your ajax or ajax+ jquery function onkeypress event. for get data you can user $.post, $.ajax, $.get method of jquery or you can use simple ajax function which will retrieve data from your middle file.